# How can I copy and paste a file in Windows using C++?

Tags: c++, windows, file, fstream

I have googled this, but I am still confused about how to use it.  I am making a file manager, and I want to be able t o copy and paste a file into a new directory.  I know to copy I need to use `file.copy()`, but I am not sure how to implement it into my code.

I would like to do this using fstream.

Comment: `CopyFile` does work, but how can I do this using fstream.

Comment: Then you should change the title of your question and specify that in the question instead of asking to copy paste in windows...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using the Win32 API then consider looking into the functions [`CopyFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`CopyFileEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363852%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You can use the first in a way similar to the following:

```
CopyFile( szFilePath.c_str(), szCopyPath.c_str(), FALSE );
```

This will copy the file found at the contents of `szFilePath` to the contents of `szCopyPath`, and will return `FALSE` if the copy was unsuccessful. To find out more about why the function failed you can use the [`GetLastError()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function and then look up the error codes in the Microsoft Documentation.

Comment: I am not using WinAPI

Comment: No, but you did say you are working "in Windows", which means you have access to the Win32 API. There is no standard C++ wrapper that does the same thing `CopyFile/Ex()` does. If you want a purely C++ solution, you would have to create and open the destination file, and then manually loop through the source file copying bytes to the destination file, like Nisarg and dieram3 showed. Not as efficient as using a native OS solution.

Comment: I *strongly recommend* calling the API function instead of rolling your own.

Comment: This doesn't work in Windows 2008 R2, but it works in 2003. Why?

Answer (score 4):

```
void copyFile(const std::string &from, const std::string &to)
{
    std::ifstream is(from, ios::in | ios::binary);
    std::ofstream os(to, ios::out | ios::binary);

    std::copy(std::istream_iterator(is), std::istream_iterator(),
          std::ostream_iterator(os));
}
```

Comment: Should be `istream_iterator<char>`, or better yet `istreambuf_iterator<char>`. Likewise for `ostream`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my implementation to copy a file, you should take a look at boost filesystem since that library will be part of the standard c++ library.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <memory>

//C++98 implementation, this function returns true if the copy was successful, false otherwise.

bool copy_file(const char* From, const char* To, std::size_t MaxBufferSize = 1048576)
{
    std::ifstream is(From, std::ios_base::binary);
    std::ofstream os(To, std::ios_base::binary);

    std::pair<char*,std::ptrdiff_t> buffer;
    buffer = std::get_temporary_buffer<char>(MaxBufferSize);

    //Note that exception() == 0 in both file streams,
    //so you will not have a memory leak in case of fail.
    while(is.good() and os)
    {
       is.read(buffer.first, buffer.second);
       os.write(buffer.first, is.gcount());
    }

    std::return_temporary_buffer(buffer.first);

    if(os.fail()) return false;
    if(is.eof()) return true;
    return false;
}

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   bool CopyResult = copy_file("test.in","test.out");

   std::boolalpha(std::cout);
   std::cout << "Could it copy the file? " << CopyResult << '\n';
}
```

The answer of Nisarg looks nice, but that solution is slow.

Comment: what does this line means? 
while(is.good() and os)

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851(v=vs.85).aspx

I don't know what you mean by copy and paste a file; that makes no sense. You can copy a file to another location and I assume that's what you are asking about.

Comment: That is what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

In native C++, you can use:

- The CopyFile function : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
- CopyFileEx function for more advanced options like progress notifications. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363852%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Using C makes C++ projects more portable. Here my sample code is a reference for you.

```
int file_copy(char* fn_dst, char* fn_src) {
    FILE* pf = NULL;
    char* buf = NULL;   
    int len = 0;
    
    //get length of file src
    pf = fopen(fn_src, "r");
    if (pf == NULL) {
        printf("[%s]Failed to fopen:%s\n", __func__, fn_src);
        return -1;
    }
    fseek(pf, 0, SEEK_END);
    len = ftell(pf);
    fclose(pf);
    //allocate buf
    buf = (char*)malloc(len);
    if (buf == NULL) {
        printf("[%s]Failed to malloc\n", __func__);
        return -1;
    }
    memset(buf, 0, len);
    //read from file src
    pf = fopen(fn_src, "rb");
    if (pf == NULL) {
        printf("[%s]Failed to fopen:%s\n", __func__, fn_src);
        return -1;
    }
    fread(buf, 1, len, pf);
    fclose(pf);
    //write into file dst
    pf = fopen(fn_dst, "wb+");
    if (pf == NULL) {
        printf("[%s]Failed to fopen:%s\n", __func__, fn_dst);
        return -1;
    }
    fwrite(buf, 1, len, pf);
    fclose(pf);

    if (buf)
        free(buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

System::IO::File::Copy("Old Path", "New Path");

Comment: Ali, could you please remove this answer? There are a couple of existing and better answers, already. If you have a critic to any of them, just gain enough reputation for commenting. At the very least, provide some explanation, including some MSDN documentation, et cetera. It is a low-quality post as it stands.

Comment: This is not Java Language