# Run batch file from VC++

Tags: visual-c++, batch-file

I am trying to copy files to `C:\Windows\System32...` from VC++ by using `ShellExecute` to run a batch file, and this is what my batch file runs

```
xcopy /S/E "source" "C:\Windows\System32\test.dll" /y
```

The problem is that when I'm running this batch file from VC++, it will be copied to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`, but when I double click the batch file, it copy to where I want `C:\Windows\System32...`

What should I do to make it copy to `System32` from VC++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I must say that running a batch file from an executable just to copy a file is too clumsy and inefficient. There are many APIs for copying files, otherwise how can `xcopy` or `copy` do their jobs? You just need to call the appropriate one like [`CopyFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-copyfile) or [`CopyFileExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-copyfileexw). Before running any external commands from your executable, always search MSDN for the API, there are always a better solution

See [How can I copy and paste a file in Windows using C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17929713/995714)

---

Back to the question, that's because of the [file system redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector). If you compile your program as 32-bit then that *.bat file will run in the 32-bit cmd.exe. But when you double click it, 64-bit cmd.exe will execute instead, which is why you see the result like that.

You can compile the program as 64-bit if you don't need to support 32-bit platform. If you must compile the program as 32-bit you'll need to disable filesystem redirection as mentioned on MS's website, or use `%windir%\SysNative`

But no need to run a batch file like that, just run it directly from cmd.exe. The following command

```
cmd /c xcopy /S/E "source" "C:\Windows\System32\test.dll*" /y
```

will run the command after `/c`. Make sure to run the correct 32-bit or 64-bit version of cmd

In 32-bit programs if you don't disable filesystem redirection then you'll need to run the correct version of cmd.exe with the correct folder. Use the following command to run 32-bit cmd.exe

```
system("cmd.exe /c xcopy /S/E \"source\" \"%windir%\\Sysnative\\test.dll*\" /y"); // or
system(R"(cmd.exe /c xcopy /S/E "source" "%windir%\Sysnative\test.dll*" /y)")
```

or the following to run 64-bit cmd

```
system("%windir%\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe /c xcopy /S/E \"source\" \"%windir%\\System32\\test.dll*\" /y"); // or
system(R"(%windir%\Sysnative\cmd.exe /c xcopy /S/E "source" "%windir%\System32\test.dll*" /y)");
```

The easiest way is to change your project to 64-bit and run as normal

```
system("xcopy /S/E \"source\" \"%windir%\\System32\\test.dll*\" /y"); // or
```

Comment: thanks, but it is not working when running from vc. this is how i write..
_system("cmd /c xcopy \"source\" \"C:\Windows\System32\test.dll*\" /y");_

Comment: if you use system() then just `system("xcopy \"source\" \"C:\Windows\System32\test.dll*\" /y");` is enough. Otherwise you should run `system("cmd.exe /c xcopy \"source\" \"C:\Windows\System32\test.dll*\" /y");`

Comment: i have tried both, and try to run 32 and 64-bit cmd. but it only will copy to SysWow64...

Comment: You should specify the correct cmd.exe and folder path as I've just edited

Answer (score 0):

Check two important aspects:

- Is you application a 32-bit or a 64-bit process?
- The current directory

Also ensure you may need to comment out `REM` marked lines, process the environment variables etc.

Comment: thanks, but how to check whether my application is 32/64-bit?
the directories are no problem.

Comment: Only 32-bit programs be run under redirection like that.
@Terrence: check architecture compile option in VS on the right of debug/release option