# Move a text file from one location to another in Turbo C++

Tags: c++, turbo-c++, dosbox

I have been trying to use the following code snippet to move a text file from one location to another (to a folder on the Desktop). However, the method of using the REN function of DOSBox or the rename function of C++ has failed.

```
char billfile[] = "Text.txt";
char path[67] = "ren C:\\TURBOC3\\Projects\\";
strcat(path, billfile);
strcat(path, " C:\\Users\\Admini~1\\Desktop\\Bills");
system(path);
```

Are there any other alternatives to this?

P.S.: This is for a school project, where Turbo C++ has to be used

Comment: What is `errno`  after the `rename` function failed?

Comment: Does Turbo C++ provides access to the Windows API functions? In that case you should use just the right function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-movefilew

Comment: Just want to say sorry that you are stuck using a DOS VM and 1980s toolchains.

Comment: Could be something to do with `ren` being a built-in. Have you at least verified that `path` is what you expect?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Why do you expect `system("ren A B")` to set a meaningful errno?

Comment: I mentioned the [rename](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/rename) standard C function (without using `system`). I don't know if TurboC has it, but it standard in C

Comment: @harper Being a 16-bit compiler, Borland does not support WinAPI, which would have been useful

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Originally I hadn't checked, but on checking, rename() returns -1. Also I might add that rename() works with the exact same files and locations when used in a standalone program, that is, the file is renamed and shifted to the required location with return value zero when used in a standalone program. (This code snippet is from a .cpp file included in a Turbo C++ project).

Comment: Just a silly question but You are running  inside DOS Box  and the path `"C:\\Users\\Admini~1\\Desktop\\Bills" `  suggest windows so are you sure that path exists inside your DOS Box (may be shared folder?)? also the LFN name truncated to `8.3` can have different number than just `~1` on different machines (I would use `dir` to check it)... Another problem might be a policy problem do you got the priviledges to access/move/copy files withing target and source folders? (try to run the app as Administrator). btw there are alternatives you can use DOS FN interrupt or C++ file access

Comment: also did you try to type that directly in DOS prompt without C++? not sure if you can rename directory this way  (in case it is only for files may be use `MOVE` command instead)

Answer (score 2):

Corresponding to this website for [stdio.h](http://www.softwareandfinance.com/Turbo_CPP/HeaderFiles/stdio.html) the TurboC run-time library supports the rename function.

So even if you are obliged to use a totally outdated tool like TurboC++ it's not necessary to spawn a new process with the `system` function just to rename the file.

Comment: The rename() function is working in standalone programs. The rename function works properly with project files too, when renaming files within the same project folder, but I cannot use rename() to shift files from the project folder to any other folder (say the Desktop).

Comment: @CPROG So you see the result of fighting at the wrong frontier. You should consider to use a tool that is not aged out. Try a contemporary tool like Visual Studio Community edition. I can't see any reason to program for stone age.

Comment: It would have been much easier to use a more modern IDE, but since it is for a school project, we have no choice but to use Turbo

Comment: It's completely irresponsible to teach pupils with bifaces or stone axes. What kind of school hides free, effective, easy to learn tools like this: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the Win32 API then consider looking into the functions CopyFile or CopyFileEx.

You can use the first in a way similar to the following:

CopyFile( szFilePath.c_str(), szCopyPath.c_str(), FALSE );

This will copy the file found at the contents of szFilePath to the contents of szCopyPath, and will return FALSE if the copy was unsuccessful. To find out more about why the function failed you can use the GetLastError() function and then look up the error codes in the Microsoft Documentation.

Comment: The answer is taken from the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17929713/how-can-i-copy-and-paste-a-file-in-windows-using-c

Comment: This is not a duplicate, but it's a wrong answer. The question was about *moving* a file, not copy.

Comment: You can delete the source file after the copy operation.

Comment: Windows? This is DOSBox.